# Multiple KotlinJavaRuntime at External Libraries in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

How to remove the extra KotlinJavaRuntime at External Libraries?
My External Libraries has multiple KotlinJavaRuntime.
MacOS Big Sur ver.11.4
IntelliJ IDEA ver.2021.1.2 (Community Edition)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itUsR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select this library from the External Libraries node and use Main Menu | View | **Jump to Source** action (F4 default shortcut) to open this library in the Project Structure dialog.
2. Then check if this library is used in any of the project's modules by using Main Menu | Edit | Find Usages | **Find Usages** action (Alt+F7 default shortcut):

[image]

3. If the library is not used in any of the modules - just remove it from the project structure.